# how to select a complete row on pressing a key and then search the element stored in the JTable and select that row?

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable

i have a JTable and JLabel , i have put some values in the Table !
i want to implement search in that table and then set the value from the searched value on the JLabel.

suppose i type 'f' so myfunction will search where in myTable's row and 0th column the value starts with f , thus i ll get that row value ! now i want to select/highlight that entire row and print the value on JLabel.

I don't know how to highlight this row!
is there any better method to do searching , i have read about SwingX , but i did not find how to actually use JXTables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better for you to use the `filtering` capabilities of JTable.

The Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) give a working example on how this can be done to filter all the rows that start with the text entered in your text field.

I don't understand your question about updating a "label", since it is possible that multiple rows could start with the search string.

Comment: no just the first value , then the end user can scroll down and have used up and down keys event to set the value.

Comment: I don't understand the comment. It still doesn't change my suggestion. User the filter to limit the visible rows that contain the entered string. Then use the up/down arrows to change the data in the table.