# Editable JcomboBox Action event on key released not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox named c , which i have kept editable , i want to call a function named search() whenever any key is pressed/released in that ComboBox  ? i tried this but this neither calls my function nor does the job i have written in if() when the condition is true.

Please let me know how to fire an action when a key is pressed from keyboard through an editable combobox , i m using netbeans.

```
private void cKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                              

     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A )
    {
        //DOES NOT EVEN ENTER THIS METHOD WHEN A IS PRESSED.
        try 
         {
             search();      // MY CALL TO FUNCTION
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }

     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_B )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_C )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_D )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_E )
    {
         try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_G )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_I )
    {
        try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_J )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_K )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_L )
    {
      try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_M )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_N )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }




     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_P )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Q )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_R )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S )
    {

         try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_T )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }



     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_U )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_V )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }

    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W )
    {

         try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    } 

    if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_X )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }

     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Y )
    {

         try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }

   if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_Z )
    {

         try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }  

     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_1 )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_2 )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_3 )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_4 )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_5 )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_6 )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_7 )
    {
          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_8 )
    {

          try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_9 )
    {
         try 
         {
             search();
         } catch (     ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) 
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }


    }


     if(evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_0 )
    {
         try 
         {
             search();
         }
         catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }

    }


}
```

Comment: JCommboBox uses an editor, you should consider using a DocumentListener instead of a KeyListener

Comment: please a little more information to make your answer clear ! i m unaware about Document Listener.

Comment: `i m unaware about Document Listener` -  If you don't know what a DocumentListener is then do some searching of the forum or the web. You posted that comment less than 1 minute after receiving the suggestion. There is no way you could have searched the web in less than a minute. Did you even look at the Swing tutorial, which has a section that provides a working example. You were given a link to the Swing tutorial in your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24084980/131872). I gave you a link to the tutorial so you could use it as a resource for future questions.

Comment: @camickr , you are kind enough to instruct me and i appreciate that but with all due respect , i did my research i m a beginner and i m trying my best to learn java from scratch ! i just wanted a better explanation for document listener not the delightful speech which you gave to upstage yourself.

Comment: @user3503308, `i did my research` - with all due respect there is no way you did your research in less than a minute on using a DocumentListener. It has been 5 hours since the suggestion. What have you learned? Did the suggestion help solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I USED THIS , EVEN KEY LISTENER DID THE JOB , i did not need document listener @camickr trust me , all i wanted was  how to use document listener , i still would love to use it ! i repeat i m new to java and i m developing a project by reading question and answers molding them to fit my requirements !
when i say i did my research , i mean i did it even  before posting my question sir.
again a small snippet of how to use document listener would be of great help , as i m using netbeans i just want to make a function call whenever key is typed in my editable combobox.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.ComboBoxEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.text.DateFormatter;


public class Adhoc_JComboBox extends JFrame implements KeyListener{

private static JComboBox combobox; 
String a1,a2,a3;
public static void main(String[] args) {
new Adhoc_JComboBox();
}

private Adhoc_JComboBox(){
String array[]= new String[3];

a1=new String("a1");
a2=new String("a2");
a3=new String("a3");
array[0]= a1;
array[1]= a2;
array[2]= a3;
combobox = new JComboBox(array);
combobox.setEditable(true);
JTextField editor = (JTextField) combobox.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
editor.addKeyListener(this);
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(combobox);
pack();
setVisible(true);
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
System.out.println("Key Typed " +arg0.getKeyCode());
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
System.out.println("Key Pressed " +arg0.getKeyCode());
} 
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
System.out.println("Key Released " +arg0.getKeyCode());}}
```